# c++ template linked list which can hold any types

Tags: templates, types

How to define a list which can hold different types of objects in c++, just like python list? I tried the following code

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename t >
struct Node {
    t val;
    Node *next;
};

int main() {
    Node<int> a;
    a.val = 1;
    Node<char> b;
    b.val = 'b';
    a.next = &b;
    b.next = NULL;
}
```

But compiler gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:14:15: error: cannot convert 'Node<char>*' to 'Node<int>*' in 
assignment
     a.next = &b;
           ^
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you Google about it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple problems with this code, first of which is the next member of Node does not have a template type defined, usually in this case if you want to make a linked list of one generic type you would do something like `Node<t>* next`. Second is the fact that you are assigning what seems to be an Node* to a Node*.

If what you are trying to do is create a linked list of different types you cannot do it this way. Simply put, the reason is because you have to pass in a type for the `t` argument and because of this each node must have a **defined** type. The purpose of template classes is not to allow user to allocate any generic type willy nilly but rather to simplify repeated implementation of a class by allowing you to pass in a type as a parameter. As an example: a `List<int>` vs a `List<char>` simplyfies you from having to make a `IntList` class and a `CharList` class.

If you want the behavior of storing any dynamically allocated types within the same array then this is not as easy. I would recommend looking at c++17 `std::any` and `std::variant` types or if older version of the language the boost `boost::any` and `boost::variant` types from the boost library. Other ways to do this without the standard libraries is by using polymorphism or `void*`.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! I haven't done any c++ template programming before, Now I understand what is c++ template programming for and the difference between compiled language and interpreted language. Here is the [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generic-linked-list-in-c-2/) to create a generic linked list in c